# Eigenspaces of 2x2 Jacobian matrix with change of variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, diagonalization, hyperbolic-equations

Let
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
v & \rho\\
v\left(v+2\rho\right) & \rho\left(2v+\rho\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\rho>0$, $v=\alpha-\rho$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Show that $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1(\rho,v)<\lambda_2(\rho,v)$ and compute a basis of eigenvectors assoiated to these eigenvalues.

**My work**
We have
$$\det(\lambda I_2-A)=\lambda^2-(v+\rho(2v+\rho))\lambda+v\rho(v-\rho)$$
The discriminant is
$$\Delta=v^2+4\rho^2v^2+\rho^4+4\rho^3v+6v\rho^2$$

I cannot seem to find a way to show that it is strictly positive. Even if I assume it is, I do not know how to find easily the eigenvectors (apart from resolving a system which will take a very long time). There has to be something that I am missing.

PS: this comes from an hyperbolic PDE where I need to show the system hyperbolicity:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_t \rho+\partial_x(\rho(\alpha-\rho))=0\\
\partial_t(\rho\alpha)+\partial_x(\rho\alpha(\alpha-\rho))=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and we chose the change of variables ${\bf u} =(\rho,\alpha\rho)\to {\bf v} = (\rho,v)$ with $v=\alpha-\rho$.

Comment: Though I have not come up with full solution, but it appears to me that $A(\rho,v)$ has some nice properties: For example, switching $v$ and $\rho$ simply exchange the columns of $A$. You might consider making a good use of it.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then the corresponding eigenvector is $(\rho, v-\lambda)^{T}$ ( in case when $\rho\not=0$, but the case $\rho=0$ is altogether trivial).

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm sorry but this does not seem to be the case. The computation of the first component indicates that it should be $(\rho,\lambda-v)^T$, but in that case the second component does not fit.
In any case, how did you get to that proposition ?

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgot to negate the second term. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue the second term *must* fit, as $A-\lambda$ has rank at most $1$.

Comment: @Flewer47 So in other words, $(\rho, \lambda - v)^T$ will be an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ whenever $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial system reads \begin{aligned}
\rho_t + (\rho (\alpha-\rho))_x &= 0 \\
(\rho\alpha)_t + (\rho\alpha (\alpha - \rho))_x &= 0
\end{aligned}
for the conserved variables ${\bf u} = (\rho, \rho\alpha)$.
Now we introduce the new vector of conserved variables $
{\bf v} = (\rho, \alpha-\rho)
$. With $v=\alpha-\rho$, the first equation of our system rewrites as
$$
\rho_t + (\rho v)_x = 0
$$
and the second one becomes $$
(\rho (\rho+v))_t + (\rho v (\rho+v))_x = 0 \, .
$$
Using the first equation and the product rule, we may rewrite the latter as
$$
v_t + (v-\rho) v_x = 0 \, ,
$$
where we have also used $\rho\neq 0$.
Therefore, the Jacobian matrix of the flux such that ${\bf v}_t + A {\bf v}_x = \bf 0 $ reads $$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
v & \rho\\
0 & v-\rho
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which eigenvalues are the diagonal entries. They are distinct provided $\rho>0$, and the system is then strictly hyperbolic.

Comment: The initial PDE is 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_t\rho+\partial_x(\rho(\alpha-\rho))=0\\
\partial_t\rho\alpha+\partial_x(\rho\alpha(\alpha-\rho))=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and to show that the system is strictly hyperbolic, it is said to use the change of variables $\mathbf{u}=(\rho,\rho\alpha)\to \mathbf{v}=(\rho,v)$ where $v=\alpha-\rho$.

Comment: I may have done some mistakes. Replacing for the change of variables, I have:
$\alpha\partial_t\rho+\rho\partial_t\alpha+\alpha\partial_x(\rho(\alpha-\rho))+\rho(\alpha-\rho)\partial_x\alpha=0$ and using the first equation, and simplifying by $\rho>0$, we have 
$\partial_t\alpha+(\alpha-\rho)\partial_x\alpha=0$. As we want $v$ and not $\alpha$, it becomes 
$\partial_t v+\partial_t\rho+v\partial_x v+v\partial_x \rho=0$ and using the first equation again,,
$\partial_t v+(v-\rho)\partial_x v=0$
and the Jacobian matrix becomes 
$$A
=\begin{pmatrix}
v&\rho\\
0&v-\rho
\end{pmatrix}
$$
?

Comment: @Flewer47 That's the way to go! Answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Note that we can write
$$
\Delta=v^2+4\rho^2v^2+\rho^4+4\rho^3v+6v\rho^2\\
= (1+4\rho^2)v^2+(4\rho^3+6\rho^2)v + \rho^4
$$
Consider the polynomial $p(v) = \Delta$. We see that this is a quadratic function with positive coefficients, so it will hold that $p(v) \geq 0$ for all $v$ if and only if *its discriminant* is either zero or negative. We find the discriminant of $p$ to be
$$
\Delta_v = (4\rho^3 + 6\rho^2)^2 - 4\rho^4(1 + 4 \rho^2) = 48\rho^5 + 32\rho^4.
$$
For positive $\rho$, $\Delta_v$ is positive. So, there must exist a value of $v$ for which $\Delta$ is negative, which in turn means that there are complex eigenvalues, contrary to your supposition.

Comment: Thumbs up for the answer as it answered the initial post I made (when I did wrong calculations to obtain the matrix I suggest in the post). See the comments under the accepted answer for what I corrected.

Comment: @Flewer47 Wow, that makes things much clearer. I guess it's good I made you aware of the mistake